# Report/Reports on model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I just create a model with relations with other once but I'm surprised about the pluralize option of rails. I mean.

I create the model like this:

```
rails g model Report name:string....
```

like I did with:

```
rails g model Patient name:string...
rails g model Doctor name:string....
```

Doctor has many Patients so I can go to the console and type:

```
patient.doctor => gives me the doctor from a patient
doctor.patients => gives me all patients from a doctor (note patients in plural)
```

And here is the strange thing, I did exactly the same with report and I expect to have the command:

```
patient.reports (note plural)
```

But instead of this if I want to retrieve the patient reports I have to do:

```
patient.report (note singular)... AND IT WORKS!
```

Does anyone can illuminate my blindness?

Comment: it depends on the relations between the two objects: patient.reports implies that you've declared in the Patient model `has_many :reports` (note the plural here)

Comment: OMG!!! Thanks MrYoshiji it was exactly this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods to retrieve the related object(s) depends on how you've declared it in the Model.

Some examples:

```
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :doctor # singular
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients # plural
end
```

Then you can do:

```
patient.doctor # => return the associated doctor if exists
doctor.patients # => return the patients of this doctor if exist
```

I think you've declared your relation in singular:

```
# What I think you have
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :report
end
```

But you should use plural here:

```
# What I think you should use
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reports
                  ^
                  # Make it plural
end
```